# How to hide label attribute of select's option?

Tags: jquery, attributes, hide

please tell me how to hide label attribute of select's option

```
<select>
  <option label='.65' value='10'>10 gram</option>
  <option label='.23' value='20'>20 gram</option>
  <option label='.85' value='30'>30 gram</option>
</select>
```

in firefox its ok but in google chrome it displays the label in front end instead of the text
i.e 
in firfox front end it will displays

```
10 gram
20 gram
30 gram
```

and in google chrome

```
.65
.23
.85
```

Comment: its working fine for me. no issue in google crome.

Comment: Take a look at this article http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_label.asp which states that the label attribute is supported in all major browsers except Firefox. The label attribute specifies the shorter version of an option and will be displayed in the dropdown list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you change label to lab or something else, it will show same as in Firefox.